# How to regrid a netCDF using bilinear interpolation?

Tags: ubuntu, netcdf

I am looking for a procedure to apply bilinear interpolation to change the resolution of netCDF file `(1.5°x1.5°) ---> (1.25°x0.9375°)`

Edit:

I have been reading some pages and I found a function called `remapbil`. It comes from `Climate Data Operator (CDO)`. I tried to do the regrid but it did not work. This is my netCDF file info:

```
    File format: netCDF
    -1 : Institut Source   Ttype    Levels Num  Gridsize Num Dtype : Parameter name
     1 : unknown  unknown  instant       1   1       180   1  I16  : tp            
   Grid coordinates :
     1 : lonlat       > size      : dim = 180  nx = 12  ny = 15
                        longitude : first = 279  last = 295.5  inc = 1.5  degrees_east
                        latitude  : first = 15  last = -6  inc = -1.5  degrees_north
   Vertical coordinates :
     1 : surface                  : 0 
   Time coordinate :  324 steps
     RefTime =  1900-01-01 00:00:00  Units = hours  Calendar = standard
  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
  1979-01-01 03:00:00  1979-02-01 03:00:00  1979-03-01 03:00:00  1979-04-01 03:00:00
  1979-05-01 03:00:00  1979-06-01 03:00:00  1979-07-01 03:00:00  1979-08-01 03:00:00
  1979-09-01 03:00:00  1979-10-01 03:00:00  1979-11-01 03:00:00  1979-12-01 03:00:00
  1980-01-01 03:00:00  1980-02-01 03:00:00  1980-03-01 03:00:00  1980-04-01 03:00:00
  1980-05-01 03:00:00  1980-06-01 03:00:00  1980-07-01 03:00:00  1980-08-01 03:00:00
  1980-09-01 03:00:00  1980-10-01 03:00:00  1980-11-01 03:00:00  1980-12-01 03:00:00
  1981-01-01 03:00:00  1981-02-01 03:00:00  1981-03-01 03:00:00  1981-04-01 03:00:00
  1981-05-01 03:00:00  1981-06-01 03:00:00  1981-07-01 03:00:00  1981-08-01 03:00:00
  1981-09-01 03:00:00  1981-10-01 03:00:00  1981-11-01 03:00:00  1981-12-01 03:00:00
  1982-01-01 03:00:00  1982-02-01 03:00:00  1982-03-01 03:00:00  1982-04-01 03:00:00
  1982-05-01 03:00:00  1982-06-01 03:00:00  1982-07-01 03:00:00  1982-08-01 03:00:00
  1982-09-01 03:00:00  1982-10-01 03:00:00  1982-11-01 03:00:00  1982-12-01 03:00:00
  1983-01-01 03:00:00  1983-02-01 03:00:00  1983-03-01 03:00:00  1983-04-01 03:00:00
  1983-05-01 03:00:00  1983-06-01 03:00:00  1983-07-01 03:00:00  1983-08-01 03:00:00
  1983-09-01 03:00:00  1983-10-01 03:00:00  1983-11-01 03:00:00  1983-12-01 03:00:00
  1984-01-01 03:00:00  1984-02-01 03:00:00  1984-03-01 03:00:00  1984-04-01 03:00:00
  1984-05-01 03:00:00  1984-06-01 03:00:00  1984-07-01 03:00:00  1984-08-01 03:00:00
  1984-09-01 03:00:00  1984-10-01 03:00:00  1984-11-01 03:00:00  1984-12-01 03:00:00
  1985-01-01 03:00:00  1985-02-01 03:00:00  1985-03-01 03:00:00  1985-04-01 03:00:00
  1985-05-01 03:00:00  1985-06-01 03:00:00  1985-07-01 03:00:00  1985-08-01 03:00:00
  1985-09-01 03:00:00  1985-10-01 03:00:00  1985-11-01 03:00:00  1985-12-01 03:00:00
  1986-01-01 03:00:00  1986-02-01 03:00:00  1986-03-01 03:00:00  1986-04-01 03:00:00
  1986-05-01 03:00:00  1986-06-01 03:00:00  1986-07-01 03:00:00  1986-08-01 03:00:00
  1986-09-01 03:00:00  1986-10-01 03:00:00  1986-11-01 03:00:00  1986-12-01 03:00:00
  1987-01-01 03:00:00  1987-02-01 03:00:00  1987-03-01 03:00:00  1987-04-01 03:00:00
  1987-05-01 03:00:00  1987-06-01 03:00:00  1987-07-01 03:00:00  1987-08-01 03:00:00
  1987-09-01 03:00:00  1987-10-01 03:00:00  1987-11-01 03:00:00  1987-12-01 03:00:00
  1988-01-01 03:00:00  1988-02-01 03:00:00  1988-03-01 03:00:00  1988-04-01 03:00:00
  1988-05-01 03:00:00  1988-06-01 03:00:00  1988-07-01 03:00:00  1988-08-01 03:00:00
  1988-09-01 03:00:00  1988-10-01 03:00:00  1988-11-01 03:00:00  1988-12-01 03:00:00
  1989-01-01 03:00:00  1989-02-01 03:00:00  1989-03-01 03:00:00  1989-04-01 03:00:00
  1989-05-01 03:00:00  1989-06-01 03:00:00  1989-07-01 03:00:00  1989-08-01 03:00:00
  1989-09-01 03:00:00  1989-10-01 03:00:00  1989-11-01 03:00:00  1989-12-01 03:00:00
  1990-01-01 03:00:00  1990-02-01 03:00:00  1990-03-01 03:00:00  1990-04-01 03:00:00
  1990-05-01 03:00:00  1990-06-01 03:00:00  1990-07-01 03:00:00  1990-08-01 03:00:00
  1990-09-01 03:00:00  1990-10-01 03:00:00  1990-11-01 03:00:00  1990-12-01 03:00:00
  1991-01-01 03:00:00  1991-02-01 03:00:00  1991-03-01 03:00:00  1991-04-01 03:00:00
  1991-05-01 03:00:00  1991-06-01 03:00:00  1991-07-01 03:00:00  1991-08-01 03:00:00
  1991-09-01 03:00:00  1991-10-01 03:00:00  1991-11-01 03:00:00  1991-12-01 03:00:00
  1992-01-01 03:00:00  1992-02-01 03:00:00  1992-03-01 03:00:00  1992-04-01 03:00:00
  1992-05-01 03:00:00  1992-06-01 03:00:00  1992-07-01 03:00:00  1992-08-01 03:00:00
  1992-09-01 03:00:00  1992-10-01 03:00:00  1992-11-01 03:00:00  1992-12-01 03:00:00
  1993-01-01 03:00:00  1993-02-01 03:00:00  1993-03-01 03:00:00  1993-04-01 03:00:00
  1993-05-01 03:00:00  1993-06-01 03:00:00  1993-07-01 03:00:00  1993-08-01 03:00:00
  1993-09-01 03:00:00  1993-10-01 03:00:00  1993-11-01 03:00:00  1993-12-01 03:00:00
  1994-01-01 03:00:00  1994-02-01 03:00:00  1994-03-01 03:00:00  1994-04-01 03:00:00
  1994-05-01 03:00:00  1994-06-01 03:00:00  1994-07-01 03:00:00  1994-08-01 03:00:00
  1994-09-01 03:00:00  1994-10-01 03:00:00  1994-11-01 03:00:00  1994-12-01 03:00:00
  1995-01-01 03:00:00  1995-02-01 03:00:00  1995-03-01 03:00:00  1995-04-01 03:00:00
  1995-05-01 03:00:00  1995-06-01 03:00:00  1995-07-01 03:00:00  1995-08-01 03:00:00
  1995-09-01 03:00:00  1995-10-01 03:00:00  1995-11-01 03:00:00  1995-12-01 03:00:00
  1996-01-01 03:00:00  1996-02-01 03:00:00  1996-03-01 03:00:00  1996-04-01 03:00:00
  1996-05-01 03:00:00  1996-06-01 03:00:00  1996-07-01 03:00:00  1996-08-01 03:00:00
  1996-09-01 03:00:00  1996-10-01 03:00:00  1996-11-01 03:00:00  1996-12-01 03:00:00
  1997-01-01 03:00:00  1997-02-01 03:00:00  1997-03-01 03:00:00  1997-04-01 03:00:00
  1997-05-01 03:00:00  1997-06-01 03:00:00  1997-07-01 03:00:00  1997-08-01 03:00:00
  1997-09-01 03:00:00  1997-10-01 03:00:00  1997-11-01 03:00:00  1997-12-01 03:00:00
  1998-01-01 03:00:00  1998-02-01 03:00:00  1998-03-01 03:00:00  1998-04-01 03:00:00
  1998-05-01 03:00:00  1998-06-01 03:00:00  1998-07-01 03:00:00  1998-08-01 03:00:00
  1998-09-01 03:00:00  1998-10-01 03:00:00  1998-11-01 03:00:00  1998-12-01 03:00:00
  1999-01-01 03:00:00  1999-02-01 03:00:00  1999-03-01 03:00:00  1999-04-01 03:00:00
  1999-05-01 03:00:00  1999-06-01 03:00:00  1999-07-01 03:00:00  1999-08-01 03:00:00
  1999-09-01 03:00:00  1999-10-01 03:00:00  1999-11-01 03:00:00  1999-12-01 03:00:00
  2000-01-01 03:00:00  2000-02-01 03:00:00  2000-03-01 03:00:00  2000-04-01 03:00:00
  2000-05-01 03:00:00  2000-06-01 03:00:00  2000-07-01 03:00:00  2000-08-01 03:00:00
  2000-09-01 03:00:00  2000-10-01 03:00:00  2000-11-01 03:00:00  2000-12-01 03:00:00
  2001-01-01 03:00:00  2001-02-01 03:00:00  2001-03-01 03:00:00  2001-04-01 03:00:00
  2001-05-01 03:00:00  2001-06-01 03:00:00  2001-07-01 03:00:00  2001-08-01 03:00:00
  2001-09-01 03:00:00  2001-10-01 03:00:00  2001-11-01 03:00:00  2001-12-01 03:00:00
  2002-01-01 03:00:00  2002-02-01 03:00:00  2002-03-01 03:00:00  2002-04-01 03:00:00
  2002-05-01 03:00:00  2002-06-01 03:00:00  2002-07-01 03:00:00  2002-08-01 03:00:00
  2002-09-01 03:00:00  2002-10-01 03:00:00  2002-11-01 03:00:00  2002-12-01 03:00:00
  2003-01-01 03:00:00  2003-02-01 03:00:00  2003-03-01 03:00:00  2003-04-01 03:00:00
  2003-05-01 03:00:00  2003-06-01 03:00:00  2003-07-01 03:00:00  2003-08-01 03:00:00
  2003-09-01 03:00:00  2003-10-01 03:00:00  2003-11-01 03:00:00  2003-12-01 03:00:00
  2004-01-01 03:00:00  2004-02-01 03:00:00  2004-03-01 03:00:00  2004-04-01 03:00:00
  2004-05-01 03:00:00  2004-06-01 03:00:00  2004-07-01 03:00:00  2004-08-01 03:00:00
  2004-09-01 03:00:00  2004-10-01 03:00:00  2004-11-01 03:00:00  2004-12-01 03:00:00
  2005-01-01 03:00:00  2005-02-01 03:00:00  2005-03-01 03:00:00  2005-04-01 03:00:00
  2005-05-01 03:00:00  2005-06-01 03:00:00  2005-07-01 03:00:00  2005-08-01 03:00:00
  2005-09-01 03:00:00  2005-10-01 03:00:00  2005-11-01 03:00:00  2005-12-01 03:00:00
```

Then, my problem is that I don not know how to type the target grid such this:

```
cdo remapbil,r180x360 input_file.nc output_file.nc
```

I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your command looks technically correct, what is the error? What version of cdo are You using. Can You share the file You are trying to convert? But, You do not give correct coordinates, r180x360 translates into 180points lon (2 degree) and 360lat(0.5 degree), You probably want something different?

Comment: I already solved my problem. I had to construct a grid description. This is what I used. `gridtype  = lonlat
xsize     = 14
ysize     = 23
xfirst    = 279
xinc      = 1.25
yfirst    = 15
yinc      = -0.9375`
Then I ran the command and it worked. Thank you for your answer